# Scale vector along plane

Tags: vector, scale, plane

I'm trying to apply friction to a 3D collision. The information I have is:

- The velocity of the collision
- The surface normal of the collider
- An arbitrary friction coefficient (0 - 1 inclusive)

[image]

What I would like to do is multiply the portion of the velocity that is parallel to the plane by the friction coefficient, while leaving the portion parallel to the normal intact.

How can I go about performing this operation?

I was thinking perhaps this will involve the use of the dot-product, but then I started reading about matrices, then vector projection, and now I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by doing the following:

1. Get a tangent vector for the normal
2. Use the normal and the tangent vector to get a rotation matrix for the surface
3. Use the inverse of the rotation matrix to transform the velocity vector
4. Scale the x and z components of the transformed vector by the friction coefficient
5. Use the rotation matrix to transform the velocity back again

I doubt this is the most efficient way of doing it, but it seems to have worked.

Comment: Yes, you have transformed a 3D problem into a 2D aligned problem. BTW, do you deal with different coefficients of restitution also, or your collisions are purely elastic only?

Comment: I'm writing a particle simulation. The particles don't have mass, so the collisions are elastic (I think!).

Answer (score 0):

If you can do vector addition, scalar multiplication (i.e. multiplying a vector by a number) and the dot product, then this is all you need:

**V<sub>in</sub>** = (**V•V<sub>normal</sub>**)**V<sub>normal</sub>**

**V<sub>par</sub>** = **V** - **V<sub>in</sub>**

**V<sub>par</sub>** = k**V<sub>par</sub>**   (where k is the coefficient, and "=" means assignment)

**V<sub>in</sub>** = -**V<sub>in</sub>**

**V** = **V<sub>in</sub>** + **V<sub>par</sub>**

Comment: Thanks for your input Beta. My maths notation isn't great, what does => do? It also looks like Vpar isn't used in the calculation of Vin, or are there two outputs?

Comment: @Vesuvian: Sorry, I forgot the last step. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Beta, but I'm still a little confused. Does the first line mean the dot-product of the velocity and the normal, multiplied by the normal? Apologies for the hand-holding.

Comment: @Vesuvian: No need to apologize, vector algebra is confusing at first, and yes, that's exactly what it means. The dot product of two vectors is a number; (**V•Vn**) is a number. A number times a vector is a vector; (**V•Vn**) **Vn** is a vector.

Comment: Alrighty, I have an implementation, but it seems to flip one of the axis. A velocity of (0.0, -9.1, -4.9), normal (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), friction 1.0 is giving me a result of (0.0, 9.2, -4.8). I figure the magnitude is correct (just some rounding on the output) but you can see the velocity is being reflected in the Y axis.

Comment: @Vesuvian: Isn't that what you want, when you bounce off a wall?

Comment: I'm actually handling the bounce of the velocity separately, but if I'm doing both at once I would need to factor in a bounciness coefficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64194/discussion-between-beta-and-vesuvian).